# IdentityServer3 alternative to webbrowser navigating event

Tags: c#, wpf, identityserver3

I am working on a POC for IdentityServer3.

I have a version of sample app WebHost (minimal) running alright.

For the client sample app I am using the wpf client (hybrid with pkce).

I need the hybrid example because the webhost has been modified to use a custom ExternalRegistrationUserService.

However, all the samples they have for the hybrid clients use the webserver navigating event which uses a threading model not recommended for console apps/windows services.

The punchline question is, is there a console friendly equivalent to navigating that's not tied to a ui control?

httpwebrequest almost does what I want but identityserver3 seems to want to send multiple responses in a chain that I need to intercept and any httpclient or httpwebrequest call I make seems to want to return the first response only.

Comment: improved readability

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a very similar POC using information from a [recent blog post](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/07/08/update-for-authentication-api-access-for-native-applications-and-identitymodel-oidcclient/) by [Dominick Baier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/672453/leastprivilege).

Essentially, this approach has the native client app using a combination of the newish [IdentityModel.OidcClient](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/06/01/identitymodel-openid-connect-oauth-2-0-client-library-for-mobilenative-applications/) library and a local HTTP listener to receive redirects.

I contributed to one of Dominick's samples that shows how the OidcClient can be used with the HTTP listener to enable the hybrid flow in a console application. You can find the code [here](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/ConsoleSystemBrowser).

I think this sample will do what you are after, but it does externally pop open the system web browser. However, the OidcClient also supports a user supplied WebView if you wanted to do everything inside the native client.

Comment: Your solution is very promising.  It does execute and it does eliminate the need for the webbrowser control, but it also does a process.start on a fullblown browser instance which is similarly problematic for a scheduled batch app or service.  The httplistener you used I think solves the problem I was stuck on,  if the process.start can be replaced by an http client call then it will work outside a ui thread I think.  I will try to tinker with it and get back with what I find.

Comment: @Matt - Yep, full-blown browser instance was not ideal for me either. What I ended up doing was using CefSharp (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) which is a .NET wrapper around the Chromium Embedded Framework. Specifically, I used the CefSharp.OffScreen package which essentially runs a headless browser. So, instead of launching the system browser, my app instantiates the ChromiumWebBrowser with the StartUrl and then disposes it after getting the request from HttpListener.